# Multiple 2A USB Mains powered chargers

Tags: power-supply, usb, charging, mains

I'd like to know why there are no mains-powered chargers that can charge multiple usb devices at, say, 2A and 1A?

I'm after something that can charge 2 tablets that ask for 2A and 2 phones on 1A, so 6A in total. I've seen 2.5A supplies but nothing higher. Is there a fire risk or something?

Comment: No fire risk but ask yourself, how many people want this less-than-common set-up. I bet it's not a high percentage so it comes down to maximizing profit, reducing size and reducing carbon footprint sort of stuff and the standard little wall-wart fits the bill - they sell millions of them and no development required on the rarer model you might require. It comes down to market forces I reckon.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I did consider this, but I honestly thought it would be a popular item - I have four plugs taking USB-to-miniUSB charging cables. That takes up a load of space and sockets. One plug with four USB sockets would save 75% of the space.

Comment: You may be right!!!

Answer (score 1):

While the USB 2.0 standard doesn't really apply to chargers (USB 3.0 does have Battery Charger Specifications), manufacturers are free to go out of spec. And there ARE chargers that do such. While I don't have a link to it, Walgreens had a small dual port power cube, with a high current iPad (2A) usb port, and a 1A iPhone charging port. You could use both at the same time, either 2 iPhones, or one iPad and one iPhone.

A quick google for 5 Amp Usb Charger also shows some results. They exist, but just arn't common. And honestly, they don't need to be. 5 dedicated 1A chargers on a power strip is just as easy or cheap as a dedicated 5A usb strip.

Even better, google `Multiple iPad Charging Station`.
[image]
The PowerDock 5 is a 5 port, 2.1A per port, iPad charging station.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this: http://store.antec.com/Product/power/UA4-25/0-761345-29620-5%20%20.aspx which should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This is part due to the USB standard limiting the output on USB ports. The standard only specifics that it needs to reach 900mA i think. It is constantly changing.

Also companies are sure what people are charging their devices with. There is a chance(small) that a device may not be capable of handling 3 amps, of which might fry it.

There isn't anything wrong with making your own charger though.  I've main my own for charging a device.  The data pins may need to have some voltage dividing resistors on them.  Some devices(iphones, and apple) will only charge at 500mA without these resistors.

Wiring isn't to much of a risk, if they use 30 or larger, they should be able to handle 8amps

I'm making a charger for my mobile devices, and hope to have them power on the device max charge rate.
I'm using an ATX power supply to go to multiple USB charging ports. since a power supply can source upto 10+ amps at 5V i should be able to charge 5 devices at 2 amps each.

Comment: your right they will only draw what they will need. but if a device is capable of drawing 30 amps but the standard says that it will only source 700mA.  You can get problems,  Some usb devices are really cheap and don't handle some corner cases